# Timeout error with remote javascript file in Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

If i include the following http://www.google.com/jsapi js in my index.html page, its throwing time out error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Acceleration Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>

**<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>**

<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('payments', '1.0', {
'packages': ['sandbox_config']
    });
</script>
```

After some research i found that if we add the external js file we should follow the domain whitelisting for Phonegap.

I have done that by allowing all domains [*] in corodova.xml

```
<access origin=".*"/>
```

But still doesnt work. Is there any solution for this issue ?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: Hi, code has been added.

Comment: This problem may happen because of slow internet connectivity..just download all files to local and save as .js,i think this will solve your query

Comment: yes i tried that, but google jsapi.js is dynamically loading some other remote js files

Comment: don't u think it should be .js extension in http://www.google.com/jsapi this link?when u assign it to src?

Comment: ignore that one, i tried with .js also. the problem is with all external js files. for example if i include external jquery mobile library the same error occurs